# Instructions embedded in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Is there a way to make a bash script require a set of parameters when it's loaded, and if not, it will automatically spit out an `echo` to the screen giving instructions?

Looking at this example of a script called `copy`

```
user@localhost : user # ./copy  
Copy by SamplePerson  
Usage:  
copy [path/to/file] [path/to/destination]  
user@localhost : user #
```

I want it to make sure that if no parameters are given, it will automatically just spit out some predefined text on the `echo`.

I know how to ensure that the user enters correct values, but I just want the initial "usage" information be displayed for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use a construct like this:

```
case "$1" in
    'start')
        startProfile
        ;;

    'stop')
        stopProfile
        ;;

    'restart')
        stopProfile
        startProfile
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage $0 start|stop|restart <profile|application>"
esac
```

You have a switch-case that handles the normal cases and if none of them fit, then the default case prints the usage instructions.

Comment: Can you please add to your answer. I understand from:
    `'start')`, `doSomethingHere`, `;;`, `*)`

I need to know how to add `# other labels`, can you add a secondary one for me too please?

Comment: @DanijelJames: Done. If it helps you, you can also look at a more complex example, like this: https://github.com/oliversalzburg/typo3scripts/blob/master/fixPermissions.sh

Comment: I feel so silly. I literally went looking around the net, and just found the answer. It was so simple, I don't know how I overlooked it. But thank your help. This has been really appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

[ $# -eq 0 ] && cat <<XXX && exit 0;
Copy by SamplePerson
Usage:
copy [path/to/file] [path/to/destination]
XXX

echo Check args "$@"
```

Sample run:

```
# ./test.sh
Copy by SamplePerson
Usage:
copy [path/to/file] [path/to/destination]

# ./test.sh -x -y
Check args -x -y
```

You can process arguments on a very convenient way using the `getopts` [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-in  command. Or the external [getopt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) command (especially if You use long (e.g. --longopt) arguments).